# Horizontal scroll view is not scaling

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview, pinchzoom

I have to display some tables which user can pinchzoom. The table is wrapped up in a horizontal scroll view. I am scaling the layout which consists this horizontal scroll view.
When the zoom is 1,we are able to scroll horizontally completely. But when scaling is more than 1, right hand side table is clipped off. 
I am trying to scale the horizontalscrollview also. But it is not scaling.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are scaling the canvas of your layout and this canvas is actually the screen shown up or the layout visible and it will only scale the that canvas not the actual view bcoz of that your horizontal scrollview is not scalling bcoz the scrollview will expand if it's inner view expand and it's inner views are not actually scaled.
correct me if i am wrong some where.
Thanx